# Given a list of domains, how to match if a value is contained?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
EXCLUSION_DOMAINS = %w[
  example.com
  test.com
  asdf.com
  yahoo.
  gmail
]
```

Some of these exclusion domains have the full address like.com, others just a high level domain for generic matching.

Given this list, and given a value, how can I determine if the value matches one of the exclusion domains w rails 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def excluded?(value)
  EXCLUSION_DOMAINS.any? { |domain| value.include? domain }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by using that:

```
my_domain = "gmail.com.br"
EXCLUSION_DOMAINS.any? { |d| my_domain =~ /#{d}/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `string.split(".").first`
Even if there is not "." (e.g. gmail instead of gmail.) you will still get the "gmail"